# Finding the mean of the Poisson distribution using the moment generating function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

Problem:
Let $X$ have a Poisson distribution with parameters $\lambda$. Use moment generating function to find the mean and variance
of $X$.
Answer:
For the  Poisson distribution we have $M_x(t) = e^{\lambda(t-1)}$. Now, to find the mean, $u$, we compute $M_x'(0)$.
\begin{align*}
M_x'(t) &= \lambda e^{\lambda(t-1)} \\
M_x'(0) &= \lambda e^{\lambda(0-1)} = \lambda e^{-\lambda} \\
u &= \lambda e^{-\lambda}
\end{align*}
Where did I go wrong? The answer should be $\lambda$.

Here is a revised solution based upon the comments of Ekesh Kumar. I now correctly find the mean, but I get the wrong
value for the variance.
For the  Poisson distribution we have $M_x(t) = e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}$. Now, to find the mean, $u$, we compute $M_x'(0)$.
\begin{align*}
M_x'(t) &= \lambda e^t e^{\lambda(e^t-1)} \\
M_x'(0) &= \lambda e^0 e^{\lambda(e^0-1)} = \lambda  e^{\lambda(1-1)}  \\
M_x'(0) &=  \lambda \\
u &=  \lambda 
\end{align*}
Now to find $E(x^2)$, I find $M''_x(0)$.
\begin{align*}
M_x''(t) &= \lambda e^t ( \lambda e^t e^{\lambda(e^t-1) } ) + \lambda e^t \lambda e^t e^{\lambda(e^t-1)} \\
M_x''(0) &= \lambda e^0 ( \lambda e^0 e^{\lambda(e^0-1) } ) + \lambda e^0 \lambda e^0 e^{\lambda(e^0-1)} \\
M_x''(0) &= \lambda  ( \lambda  e^{\lambda(1-1) } ) + \lambda  \lambda e^0 e^{\lambda(1-1)} \\
M_x''(0) &= \lambda  ( \lambda  e^{\lambda(1-1) } ) + \lambda  \lambda  e^{\lambda(0)} \\
M_x''(0) &= \lambda \lambda + \lambda \lambda = 2{\lambda}^2 \\
\sigma_2 &= M_x''(0) - u^2 = 2{\lambda}^2 - {\lambda}^2 \\  
\sigma_2 &= {\lambda}^2
\end{align*}

Comment: That's the PGF. It only tells you anything useful when you input $t=1$.

Comment: @J.G. Are you saying to find the mean using a moment generating function, I should find $M'_x(1)$ not $M'_x(0)$?

Comment: MGF at $0$, PGF at $1$, but what you calculated is actually the PGF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's clarify the difference between two approaches. The probability-generating function$$G_X(t):=\Bbb Et^X=\sum_{k\ge0}t^ke^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}=e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda t}$$satisfies$$G_X^{(n)}(t)=\Bbb Et^X(X)_n=\lambda^ne^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda t}$$in terms of falling Pochhammer symbols, so$$\Bbb E(X)_n=G_X^{(n)}(1)=\lambda^n.$$In particular$$\begin{align}\Bbb EX&=\lambda,\\\Bbb E(X^2-X)&=\lambda^2,\\\Bbb EX^2&=\lambda^2+\lambda,\\\operatorname{Var}X&=\Bbb EX^2-(\Bbb EX)^2=\lambda^2+\lambda-\lambda^2=\lambda.\end{align}$$The moment-generating function$$M_X(t):=\Bbb Ee^{tX}=G_X(e^t)=e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda e^t}$$satisfies$$M_X^{(n)}(t)=\Bbb EX^ne^{tX}=e^{-\lambda}\frac{d^n}{dt^n}e^{\lambda e^t}$$so$$\Bbb EXe^{tX}=M_X^\prime(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda}e^te^{\lambda e^t}$$and$$\Bbb EX^2e^{tX}=M_X^{\prime\prime}(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda}e^te^{\lambda e^t}\left(1+\lambda e^t\right).$$Hence$$\Bbb EX=M_X^{\prime}(0)=\lambda e^{-\lambda}e^0e^\lambda=\lambda$$and$$\Bbb EX^2=M_X^{\prime\prime}(0)=\lambda e^{-\lambda}e^0e^{\lambda}\left(1+\lambda\right)=\lambda^2+\lambda,$$so $\operatorname{Var}X=\lambda$ by the same logic as before.

Comment: If $EX^2 = \lambda^2 + \lambda$ then I do not understand how you find that $Var X = \lambda$.

Comment: @Bob As I said, subtract the squared mean. That's how you get variance.

Comment: Can you tell me where I went wrong? Can anybody tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: @Bob Your calculation of $M_X^{\prime\prime}(t)$ is wrong due to bungling the product rule. Let $u:=\lambda e^t,\,v:=e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}$; then $M_X^{\prime\prime}=uv^\prime+u^\prime v$, but you calculated $2uv^\prime$ (or perhaps you were thinking of $uv^\prime+u^\prime v^\prime$).

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is right, but your moment generating function is wrong. It should be $M_X(t) = e^{\lambda(e^t-1)}$ as derived [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Moment_Generating_Function_of_Poisson_Distribution).